# Uncaught Error: Class 'CRM_Grant_BAO_Grant'

Tags: civigrant

We are unable to upgrade CiviCRM to 5.50.2, get a fatal error with the message Uncaught Error: Class 'CRM_Grant_BAO_Grant' while running the upgrade from UI or drush. We have Grant extension enabled, Any help would be appreciated.

CiviCRM: 5.46.3
Drupal: 9.4.0
PHP: 7.4

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the error from the php log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a [Grant Application extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/grant-application-pages) or any extension related to CiviGrant installed? If so can you disable the extension, Upgrade CiviCRM, and re-enable the extension?

Have seen a similar [issue reported](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.grantapplications/issues/184) on the Grant application which is now fixed by JMA Consulting but needs some testing. If the error you are facing relates to [Grant Application extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/grant-application-pages) then can you apply the [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.grantapplications/pull/185.patch) and Do the Civi upgrade?

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Yes, We have Grant Application extension enabled. Disabling the extension and doing CiviCRM upgrade worked. Thank you